# How to do Distributed testing using JMeter in Azure VMs over firewall

Tags: azure, jmeter, firewall, connectexception, nested-exceptions

I am trying to do distributed testing using JMeter over Azure VMs behind the firewall using the conventional ways defined in most of the articles. I have tried all the possible options defined in the [following site](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) and some other websites. I tried to define a specific port for the slave machine as the VM is over the firewall and only some specific ports are open. But nothing worked. Every time I got this following error.

> Connection refused to host: IP address: nested exception is:
>   java.net.ConnectException:Connection timed out:connect

Comment: Is it a Linux or Windows VM? Also, in addition to having to allow the port (default is 1099) in the OS firewall, you have to add an inbound rule for it in the VM's NIC's network security group.

Comment: it is windows VM. And how to add the inbound rule.

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-nsg/

Comment: So in addition to allowing inbound traffic to port 1099 in the NSG, you have to allow it in Windows firewall